# Return a blade template after a request is finished using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I've a question, I'm developing a platform with laravel and I'm using ajax, to post and that, the point is that I want to load a blade template after the ajax request ends successfully, how can I do that?

1. Controller

   ```
   public function store(Request $request) {

   $equipo = new Equipo();
   $equipo->id_usuario_crea = $request->id_usuario_crea;
   $equipo->consecutivo = $request->consecutivo;
   $equipo->nombre_equipo = $request->nombre_equipo;
   $equipo->serie = $request->serie;
   $equipo->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
   $equipo->marca = $request->marca;
   $equipo->modelo = $request->modelo;
   $equipo->id_empresa = $request->id_empresa;
   $equipo->id_sede = $request->id_sede;
   $equipo->id_ubicacion = $request->id_ubicacion;
   $equipo->id_tipo_equipo = $request->id_tipo_equipo;
   $equipo->id_proveedor = $request->id_proveedor;
   $equipo->id_estado_equipo = $request->id_estado_equipo;
   $equipo->registro_invima = $request->registro_invima;
   $equipo->foto = $request->foto;
   $equipo->id_riesgo = $request->id_riesgo;
   $equipo->save();

   if ($request->hasFile('foto') && $equipo->save() == true) {
       $path         = $request->file('foto')->store('public');
       $equipo->foto = $path;
       $equipo->save();
   }

   if($equipo->save() == true){
     // $returnHTML = view('equipos.index')->with('user', $user)->render();

       $returnHTML = view('equipos.index');
   return response()->json(array('success'=> 'El equipo se ha guardado exitosamente', 'html'=>$returnHTML));


       //return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));

   }else{
       return response()->json(['fail'=> 'Falló al intentar guardar el equipo']);
   }
   }
   ```
2. Small part of AJAX

   ```
   jQuery.ajax({
               url: "{{route('equipos.store')}}",
               method: 'post',
               data: {
                   consecutivo: consecutivo,
                   nombre_equipo: nombre_equipo,
                   serie: serie,
                   descripcion: descripcion,
                   marca: marca,
                   modelo: modelo,
                   id_empresa: empresa,
                   id_sede: sede,
                   id_ubicacion: ubicacion,
                   id_tipo_equipo: tipo_equipo,
                   id_proveedor: proveedor,
                   id_estado_equipo: estado_equipo,
                   registro_invima: registro_invima,
                   foto: foto,
                   id_riesgo: riesgo,
                   id_usuario_crea: usuario_crea
               },
               success: function(result) {
                   console.log(result);
                   swal({
                       title: "",
                       text: result.success,
                       icon: "success",
                       button: "Aceptar",
                       type: "success",
                   });

                   **//RETURN THE BLADE TEMPLATE HERE** 

               },
               fail: function(result) {
                   console.log(result);
                   sweetAlert("", result.fail, "error");
               },
               error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                   console.log(xhr.status);
                   //console.log(ajaxOptions);
                   console.log(thrownError);
               }
           });
   ```

In the case where the data is saved correctly, I am showing a sweetalert, but I also want to redirect to the "equipos" index view, but I don't know how to do it and I have searched, but, I have not found solution to this, thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just redirect the index view, I think you don't need load Html content inside ajax request, just redirect to route with js.

```
window.location.replace('URL')
```

In this state URL=route('equipos.index')

Answer (score 1):

You can return html content from controller ( return view(...) ) and replace html content on ajax.success. ( $('#ajaxResults').html( response.data ) )